# Avoid text fields for one-key shortcuts on Keyboard Maestro

Tags: applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-maestro

I'm a big fan of Gmail-like shortcuts, where you don't need to hold shift or command to actually make good use of it. Pocket and Reeder also have such, give it a shot if you don't know what I mean.

Keyboard Maestro allows to create one-key shortcuts, however, if you're typing something in a text field in an application, it will activate the one-key shortcut as soon as you hit the designated key.

The best solution I found for this is to create an "if" sentence that stops the macro if a text field is active (or cursor is active, i don't know what is possible). Or that only proceeds with the macro if a text field (or any place you can type) is not selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Quick update: There's a "solution" created by Philippe Martin [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/keyboard_maestro/message/5020). I'm not 100% satisfied with it and would be great to find alternatives.

For example, if I use his trick to delegate a different function for the spacebar in Things, such as mark selected task as done, as in The Hit List, since there's already an action attached to the spacebar (create a task below), one doesn't erase the other. Besides, you always gotta hold your key longer than you'd desire for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Your link to the solution is broken. Also, you should probably add it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @studgeek [Here's a fixed link](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/keyboard_maestro/conversations/topics/5020). I'll write an answer on the subject later, although the workaround is yet not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Karabiner.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/history.html.en

> AXNotifier has been added.  AXNotifier allows you to observe the
>   window name (window title) and the focused ui element role (eg.
>   whether textarea or not).  For example, a setting that allows you to
>   use hjkl keys as arrow keys in Finder when you are not editing text
>   such as filename has been added.